# Boiler heats up water, but radiators are not working

Tags: thermostat, boiler

The boiler should be working correctly, the hot water works and engineer came two weeks ago to check everything and it’s fine. However the radiators do not heat up. It was working correctly, then I left for the weekend and turned the knob on the boiler to 0 for radiators and now it doesn’t work. I am attaching pictures if the boiler and the thermostat. How to turn it back on? Would really appreciate any tips!

[image: boiler]

[image: thrermostat]

Comment: Silly comment, have you pressed the reset button?  If that doesn't work, turn off the power for a good 10 minutes and then try again.